# How to display logarithmic x-axis minor label?

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart, microsoft-chart-controls

I set x-axis as logarithmic scale, but it only displays the major labels, exp : **1E000, 1E001, 1E002, etc...** Now i also want to display the minor values, for example : **2E000, 3E000, 4E000,..., 2E001, 3E001, ....**.

it should look like the graph below :
[image]

It seems a simple question but i can't find the way to solve this problem. Can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post some sample code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694521/how-can-i-fix-the-number-of-minorgrid-lines-to-a-fixed-number-in-microsofts-ne/12785342#12785342).

It took me a long time to solve this one, but:

If you if you set the `MinorGrid` `Interval` to 1, then you get the traditional Logarithmic grid marks, ten per decade:

```
aChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsLogarithmic = true;
aChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.Interval = 1;
aChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.Enabled = true;
```

Comment: This is a copy of an answer that doesn't compile. Of course it doesn't compile either. Make that `aChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsLogarithmic = true;`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only way to do this is by setting the interval property of the `axis.LabelStyle` e.g.:

```
this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval = 0.1;
```

For example, setting 0.1 in a logaritmic scale, the labels show will be `10^0.1`, `10^0.2`, `10^0.3` ...

If you need something more particular, I suggest you to create the labels manually using the property `axis.CustomLabels`, even if is not so intuitive...