# How can I fix the number of MinorGrid lines to a fixed number in Microsoft's .NET 4.0 Chart?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I am trying to set a fixed number of minor grid lines in a .NET 4.0 Chart whose X axis is in a Logarithmic scale.

I try to set the "Axis.Minor.Interval" property, this only makes the grid lines disappear.

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalAutoMode = IntervalAutoMode.VariableCount;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 100d;

            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.IntervalOffsetType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Interval = 10d;

            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.IntervalOffsetType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.Interval = 5;
```

My goal is to have a logarithmic scale with a major grid every decade, showing 10 minor grid lines.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

After hours of banging my head on the wall with the same exact problem, it seems I've stumbled onto the answer:

Inexplicably, if you set the MinorGrid Interval to 1, then you get the traditional Logarithmic grid marks, ten per decade:

```
aChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsLogarithmic = true;
aChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.Interval = 1;
aChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.Enabled = true;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: please put up only tested and working code. this doesn't compile.

Comment: I updated the answer to be in C#, while it was previously in VB. A trivial change.

Answer (score 0):

same thing here.
my code with xaml :

```
<WindowsFormsHost.Child>
            <DVC:Chart
                x:Name="MyChart"
                Width="400"
                Height="250"
                BackColor="Transparent"
                Paint="IdVgChart_Paint">
                <DVC:Chart.ChartAreas>
                    <DVC:ChartArea x:Name="IdVgChartArea" BackColor="Transparent">
                        <DVC:ChartArea.AxisX>
                            <DVC:Axis
                                IntervalAutoMode="VariableCount"
                                IntervalOffset="0"
                                IntervalOffsetType="Auto"
                                IntervalType="Auto"
                                IsMarginVisible="False">
                                <DVC:Axis.MajorTickMark>
                                    <DVC:TickMark LineWidth="2" />
                                </DVC:Axis.MajorTickMark>
                                <DVC:Axis.MinorTickMark>
                                    <DVC:TickMark
                                        Enabled="True"
                                        LineWidth="1"
                                        TickMarkStyle="OutsideArea" />
                                </DVC:Axis.MinorTickMark>
                                <DVC:Axis.MajorGrid>
                                    <DVC:Grid
                                        LineColor="Gray"
                                        LineDashStyle="Dot"
                                        LineWidth="2" />
                                </DVC:Axis.MajorGrid>
                                <DVC:Axis.MinorGrid>
                                    <DVC:Grid
                                        Enabled="true"
                                        LineColor="Gray"
                                        LineDashStyle="Dot"
                                        LineWidth="1" />
                                </DVC:Axis.MinorGrid>
                            </DVC:Axis>
                        </DVC:ChartArea.AxisX>
                        <DVC:ChartArea.AxisY>
                            <DVC:Axis
                                Interval="0"
                                IntervalAutoMode="VariableCount"
                                IntervalOffset="0"
                                IntervalOffsetType="Number"
                                IntervalType="Number"
                                IsLogarithmic="True"
                                IsMarginVisible="False"
                                LogarithmBase="10"
                                Maximum="1e-4"
                                Minimum="1e-12">
                                <DVC:Axis.MajorTickMark>
                                    <DVC:TickMark LineWidth="2" />
                                </DVC:Axis.MajorTickMark>
                                <DVC:Axis.MinorTickMark>
                                    <DVC:TickMark
                                        Enabled="True"
                                        Interval="1"
                                        LineWidth="1"
                                        TickMarkStyle="OutsideArea" />
                                </DVC:Axis.MinorTickMark>
                                <DVC:Axis.MajorGrid>
                                    <DVC:Grid
                                        Enabled="True"
                                        LineColor="Gray"
                                        LineDashStyle="Dot"
                                        LineWidth="2" />
                                </DVC:Axis.MajorGrid>
                                <DVC:Axis.MinorGrid>
                                    <DVC:Grid
                                        Enabled="true"
                                        Interval="1"
                                        LineColor="Gray"
                                        LineDashStyle="Dot"
                                        LineWidth="1" />
                                </DVC:Axis.MinorGrid>
                            </DVC:Axis>
                        </DVC:ChartArea.AxisY>
                        <DVC:ChartArea.CursorX>
                            <DVC:Cursor IsUserEnabled="False" IsUserSelectionEnabled="False" />
                        </DVC:ChartArea.CursorX>
                        <DVC:ChartArea.CursorY>
                            <DVC:Cursor IsUserEnabled="False" IsUserSelectionEnabled="False" />
                        </DVC:ChartArea.CursorY>
                    </DVC:ChartArea>
                </DVC:Chart.ChartAreas>
            </DVC:Chart>
        </WindowsFormsHost.Child>
```