# Display tick labels in logarithmic scale MS Chart (log-log)

Tags: c#, charts, .net-4.5, mschart

I have a plot created with MS Charts in Visual Studio 2015 (C#) with logarithmic scales (both axes) (see figure).

**I need to add more grid lines and the corresponding labels in the x-axis. I want to label each minor tick between 1 (2, 3, 4...) and 10 and between 10 and 100 (20, 30, 40...) and, also, I want to add grid lines between e.g. 10 and 20.**

I used the Interval of `1` for the label in the axes properties of the chart but it didn't work.

[image: Chart with log scale]

Comment: Can you please provide us with the code you have tried?  What interval did you set to 1?  There are multiple intervals you could have set.  There's one for the chartArea X axis, one for the major ticks, one for the minor ticks, etc.  Being able to see your code will help you get more answers.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762059/how-to-display-logarithmic-x-axis-minor-label](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762059/how-to-display-logarithmic-x-axis-minor-label). I think they might have a solution to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After(!) adding a point at a non-zero x-value **or** setting `chart.SuppressExceptions = true` you can use these properties for a `Chartarea ca`:

```
ca.AxisX.IsLogarithmic = true;
ca.AxisX.LogarithmBase = 10;

// with 10 as the base it will go to 1, 10, 100, 1000..
ca.AxisX.Interval = 1;

// this adds 4 tickmarks into each interval:
ca.AxisX.MajorTickMark.Interval = 0.25;

// this add 8 gridlines into each interval:
ca.AxisX.MajorGrid.Interval = 0.125;

// this sets two i.e. adds one extra label per interval
ca.AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval = 0.5;
ca.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "#0.0";
```

[image]

**Update:**

Since you don't want to have automatic labels (which are always aligned by value) you need to add `CustomLabels`.

For this you need to set up a list of positions/values where you want a label to show:

```
    // pick a better name!
    List<double> xs = new List<double>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000};
```

Next we need to assign a `FromPosition`  and a `ToPosition` to each `CustomLabel` we create. This is always a little tricky but here even more than usual..

The two values need to be spaced far enough to allow a label to fit in.. So we pick a spacer-factor:

```
    double spacer = 0.9d;
```

And we also turn off the auto-fitting mechanism:

```
    ca.AxisX.IsLabelAutoFit = false;
```

Now we can add the `CustomLabels`:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < xs.Count; i++)
    {
        CustomLabel cl = new CustomLabel();
        if (xs[i] == 1 || xs[i] <= 0)
        {
            cl.FromPosition = 0f;
            cl.ToPosition = 0.01f;
        }
        else
        {
            cl.FromPosition = Math.Log10(xs[i] * spacer);
            cl.ToPosition = Math.Log10(xs[i] / spacer);
        }

        cl.Text = xs[i] + "";
        ca.AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(cl);

    }
```

As you can see we need to calculate the values using the `Log10` function that is applied to the `Axis` and the spacing is achieved by multiplying/dividing the spacer, not by adding. The spacing value must also be scaled by Log10 and is included in the function.

We also need to take care of the case of a value of `1`, which amounts to a label position of `0`; but this won't result in any spacing when multiplying/dividing it. So we set a suitable `ToPosition` manually.

I wish I knew of an easier way to do this, but as the list of label positions is really your choice, I doubt there is a short-cut..

[image]

I have added points at 40 and 50 to show how one label matches.. Also note how the label positions are somewhat mixed. Feel free to use yours!

Comment: Of course it __does__, as __you can see__ if you __just look__! The __screenshot__ is the __result of the code__!

Comment: As you may know, the spacing between ticks or grid lines in a log scale is not linear as it is in your figure. I need to add between 1 and 10: 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6...1.9 (not 3.2)

Comment: The ticks in my figure are not linear by value but they are by position. You never said you want to have hem linear by value. This is of course not possible by setting a single interval. Instead you will need to add __custom labels__ one by one where you want them. - The chart you show has non-linear ticks. Is it the real chart you want to add the labels to?

Comment: yes, that is the chart generated with MS Chars. I want to add ticks in between (eg between 10 and 11)...with an easier version than custom labels, of course...

Comment: Well, I have added an example of how to add CustomLabels. You should be able to create all the labels you want like that..