# chart with unlinear axisx scaling

Tags: c#, charts, axis, scaling, logarithm

I need your help.
I have a problem with the graph I need to create a graph with the X axis which is not linear.
I have tried every option with the option Logritmic and I could not because I get the opposite result
I attach the following picture illustrates what I need
The picture is an example from the Internet, but it describes exactly what I need X axis
If someone could help me I would appreciate it very much

[image]

The second picture shows what I have:

[image: The second picture shows what I have:]

The function of the graph is the same function but the result is different as you see

the parameaters is :
`pstati = 105`
`psheari = 90`
`currentflow = 447`
This is a Code

```
private void PlotChart()
{
    chart.Series[0].Points.Clear();
    int currentflow = 0, pstati = 0, psheari = 0;
    double ans = 0, hr, hf;
    currentflow = int.Parse(tbAnsFlow.Text);
    psheari = int.Parse(tbPSheari.Text);
    pstati = int.Parse(tbPStatic.Text);

    for (int i = 0; i <= pstati; i++)
    {
        hr = (pstati - i);
        hf = (pstati - psheari);
        ans = hr / hf;
        ans = (Math.Pow(ans, 0.54)) * currentflow;
        chart.Series[0].Points.AddXY(ans, i);
        if (i == int.Parse(tbPSheariToCalc.Text))
        {
            chart.Series[0].Points[i].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;
            chart.Series[0].Points[i].MarkerSize = 8;
            chart.Series[0].Points[i].MarkerColor = Color.Black;
            chart.Series[0].Points[i].LabelAngle = 0;
            chart.Series[0].Points[i].Label = Math.Round(ans).ToString();
            chart.Series[0].Points[i].LabelBorderColor = Color.Black;
            chart.Series[0].Points[i].LabelBackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
            tbAnsFlowCalc.Text = Math.Round(ans).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Setting `AxisX.IsLogarithmic` is the correct way. It will do just what you show us and certainly not the opposite.

Comment: I was sure that this was the answer, but it does not give the same result graph ...
There could be another definition I missing?
I get jumps of 0.1,1,10,100 .... and at regular intervals
In addition to the problem is a function graph is with strong values and I went straight to the graph
And now it does not happen

Comment: Well the intervals depend on the detail settings. If you want to fully control the intervals and create the labels at irregular interval you need to code for that. See [here for an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37244461/display-tick-labels-in-logarithmic-scale-ms-chart-log-log/37274421?s=2|1.6582#37274421)

Comment: First of all thanks for the help, the problem of graph mine is not the tags, the problem is the situation Logritmic scale is increasing the margins so that the spacing in the first moment is 0.9 and the second is already 9 in the graph that I have is declining so if margins are equal then the first interval will be the largest best and next will be smaller in terms of value or the like as his picture spreads are of equal value, but the transition between the first and second margin larger.
I hope I was clear enough to me was hard to define the difference

Comment: Well, what is the function? Did you set the correct axis.LogarithmBase? If your function has a different power you need to change it from 10 to the correct one! It would still not change a straight line to a curve, though. So do show the function!

Comment: The function is a function for calculating flow rates:
`hr = (pstati - i);
hf = (pstati - psheari);
ans = hr / hf;
ans = (Math.Pow(ans, 0.54)) * currentflow;`

Comment: And what are the variables? Can you show how you add the DataPoints?

Comment: I try to add a piece of code that explains the site but it seems too many characters
How can I raise this piece of code to see?

Comment: Do expand your answer, not a comment!

Comment: pstati = 105
psheari = 90
currentflow = 447

Comment: ok, but what are the x- and the y-values??

Comment: Ok I updated the question and I would add the promotional code work
The X axis is the parameter ans and Y axis is the parameter i of the loop

Comment: Could it be that you are using [Math.Pow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) wrong? `Math.Pow(3, 2) = 9 ` ===>  `ans = (Math.Pow( 0.54, ans)) *currentflow;` results in a straight line.

Comment: I think not, everything goes right all the results valid, only a visual problem of graph
Strong parameter is actually 0.54
There is something that can be programmatically you think otherwise?

Comment: Well the way you write the function it is __not an exponential function__.  The function is (pretty much) `x=n*sqrt(i)`. The graph is correct.

Comment: Ok function you noted `x = n * sqrt (i)` It is a function of what?
This is what is supposed to be the X axis?
I know that the graph is true that examined point by point the results are correct.
My problem is all visual I need the straight line of the graph

Comment: Hm, looking even closer at the target image, I guess you are quite right. Your function is a rational function, basically a square root; but Chart can only have __linear or logarithmic__ axes. So I'm afraid you __can't__ use it in any nice and direct way to bend the root curve into a straight line. Sorry! You could still use it but only by doing all the calculations by yourself and adding custom labels.. A lot of work!

Comment: Thanks again for all your help and expertise.
I think maybe change direction and try thinking maybe you can help me
How could I create the X axis with equal intervals (in value) and at different distances in multiples 1.85
That means with a coefficient of 1.85 between them (the second will double the distance of the first 1.85)

Comment: Unfortunately you can't really 'create' such an axis. You can only try to fake it, ie, add labels where you want them and modify all x-values to appear where you want them. I'll play with this idea tomorrow, but it will mean to either give up or take special care for many chart features, like scaling and scrolling etc..