# C# Logarithmic Plot X-Axis Spacing

Tags: c#, charts, frequency

I'm trying to generate a chart in the logarithmic scale with a set of data in a 2 dimensional array.

I set my X-Axis labelled as Frequency in MHz and my Y-Axis as amplitude in dBm and want to start my X-Axis at 30MHz.

When I set the x-axis to 30MHz it throws off my logarithmic scale. Is there a way to maintain the integrity of my logarithmic scale from 30MHz and to display the minor divisions?

Enclosed is my chart and the code used to generate the chart.

Thanks!

[Chart Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBARd.jpg)

```
for (int i = 29; i < freqdrive.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] lineSplit = freqdrive[i].Split(',');
            frequency[i] = lineSplit[0];
            pwr[i] = lineSplit[1];
            double.TryParse(frequency[i], out FreqLenDbl[i]);
            double.TryParse(pwr[i], out pwrLenDbl[i]);
            FreqLenDblMHz[i] = FreqLenDbl[i] / 1000000;
        }

        for (int i = 29; i < freqdrive.Length; i++)
        {
            this.EmissionsChart.Series["Series1"].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
            this.EmissionsChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsLogarithmic = true;
            this.EmissionsChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.Interval = 1;
            this.EmissionsChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.Enabled = true;
            this.EmissionsChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 1;
            this.EmissionsChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 1000;
            this.EmissionsChart.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(FreqLenDblMHz[i], pwrLenDbl[i]);
        }
```

Comment: add fiddle example

Comment: You may need to take control of the labels by using CustomLabels. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37244461/display-tick-labels-in-logarithmic-scale-ms-chart-log-log/37274421?s=1|59.3196#37274421) for an example with a logarithmic scale!