# i need audio frequency response graph c#

Tags: c#, winforms, audio, charts

i need logarithm x-axis based linechart for audio frequency magnitude response for c# winform , i have tested default chart and livechart but c'ant align x axis attached photo like . anybody know please help me.

sorry for my bad english

Live Chart Code :

```
            cartesianChart1.AxisY.Add(new Axis
        {
            Title = "Gain",
            MaxValue = 10,
            MinValue = -15,
            Separator = new Separator
            {
                Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb(46, 35, 35))
            }
        });

        cartesianChart1.AxisX.Add(new LogarithmicAxis
        {
            Title = "Freq",
            LabelFormatter = (value) => (Math.Pow(10, value).ToString("N0")+"Hz"),
            Base = 10,
            Separator = new Separator
            {
                Step=0,
                Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb(35, 35, 35))
            },

        });


        cartesianChart1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0);
        cartesianChart1.DisableAnimations = true;
        cartesianChart1.Hoverable = false;
        cartesianChart1.DataTooltip = null;

        var Datapoint = new ChartValues<ObservablePoint>{

                     new ObservablePoint(1, 5),
                    new ObservablePoint(5, -4),
                    new ObservablePoint(10, 6),
                    new ObservablePoint(100, 4),
                    new ObservablePoint(150, 7),
                    new ObservablePoint(1000, 2),
                    new ObservablePoint(10000, 8),
                    new ObservablePoint(15000, 2),
                    new ObservablePoint(20000, -7),

        };


        cartesianChart1.Series = new SeriesCollection(Mappers.Xy<ObservablePoint>()
            .X(point => Math.Log10(point.X))
            .Y(point => point.Y))
        {
            new LineSeries
            {

                PointGeometry = null,
                PointGeometrySize = 0,
                Values = Datapoint,

            }
        };
```

Live Chart Display :
[image: live chart display]

Default Chart Code :

```
        var r = new Random();
        float val;

        var chart = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
        chart.AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;


        chart.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "";
        chart.AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "";
        chart.AxisY.LabelStyle.IsEndLabelVisible = true;


        chart.AxisX.Minimum = 0;
        chart.AxisX.Maximum = 20000;


        chart.AxisY.Minimum = -15;
        chart.AxisY.Maximum = 10;


        chart.AxisX.Interval = 500;
        chart.AxisY.Interval = 3;
        chart.BackColor = Color.Black;


        chart1.Series.Add("Sakthi");
        chart1.Series["Sakthi"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
        chart1.Series["Sakthi"].Color = Color.Yellow;
        chart1.Series["Sakthi"].BorderWidth = 3;
        chart1.Series["Sakthi"].BorderColor = Color.Black;


        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartDashStyle.Solid;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.FromArgb(35, 35, 35);
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.FromArgb(35, 35, 35);

        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
        chart1.Legends[0].Enabled = false;


        chart.AxisY.StripLines.Add(new StripLine
        {
            BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dot,
            BorderColor = Color.White,
            StripWidth = 0
        });

        chart1.Series.Clear();
        chart1.Series.Add("Sakthi");
        chart1.Series["Sakthi"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
        chart1.Series["Sakthi"].Color = Color.Yellow;
        chart1.Series["Sakthi"].BorderWidth = 3;
        chart1.Series["Sakthi"].BorderColor = Color.Black;   


        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            val = r.Next(-15, 10);
            chart1.Series["Sakthi"].Points.AddXY(i*2000, val);
        }
```

Default Chart Display :
[image: live chart display]

i want this this type x axis label :

[image]

Comment: Could you share the code you've tried or docs that you're having trouble understanding? Also embedding the images in your question body can help users read and answer your question quickly.

Comment: So what is it you are missing from MSChart? The grid and label spacing? Also: You didn't set the x-axis to be logarithmic, did you? (`yourChartArea.AxisX.IsLogarithmic = true;`)

Comment: yes. i did AxisX.IsLogarithmic but i need label and grid style for above pic. MSchart Logarithmic pic :http://img4.imagetitan.com/img.php?image=18_mschart.jpg

Comment: MSChart will display major gridlines and labels evenly spaced. But: Do have a look [at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43667315/how-to-put-a-logarithmic-scale-with-rows-represented-in-logarithm-on-chart-in-c/43668927?s=2|57.2422#43668927), which should help with the gridlines by using the minor gridlines. For labels you may need to switch to customlabels. For an example [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37244461/display-tick-labels-in-logarithmic-scale-ms-chart-log-log/37274421?s=1|59.0932#37274421), look at the update at the lower half!

Comment: thanks. its worked great [link](https://s15.postimg.cc/54l117r1n/peq.png) , any idea to   increase 15k to 20k between space see pic.