# Problem with X-Axis when Set to Logarithmic

Tags: c#, mschart

I have a chart, it's a column chart that goes from 0.3 to 10.0 on the x-axis.

It works fine when set to linear.

I want to give the user the option to set it to a logarithmic scale.  It does change the x-axis to a log scale, but the scaling isn't right.  It's just showing 0 and 3 as points on my scale.

I'm guessing it's trying to do 0.3, 3, 30, 300, but I would like to show it as 0.001, 1, 10, 100, etc.

My Linear Chart:
[image]

My Log Chart of the same data:
[image]

My Code:

```
private void do_Size_PM10_Chart()
{
    int currentBin = 0;
    int prevBin = 0;
    int countSum = 0;

    if (MCAList.Count < 4095)
        return;

    this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        chartSizePM10.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsLogarithmic = false;
        chartSizePM10.Series.Clear();
    });

    Series s = new Series("Counts");
    s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
    s.IsVisibleInLegend = false;

    for (double i = (Spline[0].Size + BinSize); 
                i <= Spline[Spline.Count - 1].Size; i += BinSize)
    {
        currentBin = mMath.getBin(i, Spline);

        for (int j = prevBin; j < currentBin; j++)
        {
            countSum += MCAList[j];
        }

        s.Points.AddXY(i, countSum);
        //Console.WriteLine("Size, {0}, Counts, {1}", i, countSum);

        countSum = 0;
        prevBin = currentBin;
    }

    this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        chartSizePM10.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "Size (μ)";
        chartSizePM10.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "Counts";

        chartSizePM10.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "{0.###}";
        chartSizePM10.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "{0}";

        if (radioButtonLogSize.Checked)
        {
            chartSizePM10.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0.001;
            chartSizePM10.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = Spline[Spline.Count - 1].Size;
            chartSizePM10.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            chartSizePM10.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = Spline[0].Size;
            chartSizePM10.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = Spline[Spline.Count - 1].Size;
            chartSizePM10.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 0;
        }

        chartSizePM10.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsLabelAutoFit = true;
        chartSizePM10.ChartAreas[0].RecalculateAxesScale();

        chartSizePM10.Series.Add(s);

        if (radioButtonLogSize.Checked)
        {
            chartSizePM10.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsLogarithmic = true;
            chartSizePM10.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LogarithmBase = 10;
        }
    });
}
```

I've tried setting the axis interval, but it doesn't change anything, on the log scale it still showing just a 3 as a interval marker.

**Edit:** @TaW, I used the code you supplied in that answer and my axis would not change.  I think it's because my chart is setup a specific way for linear plot.  When I removed all my code for the min, max, and interval, it's working better, I'm getting better major tick marks now.  But I still can't get the minor tick marks to show up using the code you supplied, any suggestion from here?

I tried:

```
chartSizePM10.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.Interval = 0.1;
chartSizePM10.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.Enabled = true;
```

But this did not work.  Here is my current chart:
[image]

Any more suggestion?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37244461/display-tick-labels-in-logarithmic-scale-ms-chart-log-log/37274421?r=SearchResults&s=1|59.3992#37274421) should help.

Comment: Please see my edit.